# Run in command line but gives error in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to Linux. I have a test system SuSe 64 bit. I have an executable file which I installed using a rpm file. The executable run fine when I ran through command line.

linux:linux_test>path/to/executable arg1 arg2

It ran successfully but when I put the same command in a shell script, it is throwing an error of No Such Directory or File

I checked the file type using `file` command and I got the following output:

`ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/LINUX 2.4.0, stripped`

More Details:
command I am trying to execute is :
`/opt/cds/scripts/EINJ /call del force` where `/opt/cds/scripts/EINJ` is executable with path and `/call del force` are arguments passed

My shell script is contains following 2 lines :

`#!/bin/bash
/opt/cds/scripts/EINJ /call del force`

it gives me error : 
`/temp.sh: line2: /opt/cds/scripts/EINJ : No such file or directory`

I also tried by changing the command to `cd /opt/cds/scripts && ./ENIJ /call del force`

Please help me how can I execute it from shell script.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the top line of your script look like? What are you specifying as the interpreter? `#!/bin/bash`? Is this Leap 42.3? What executable are you attempting to run?

Comment: I did not specified any interpreter, I just added the command in the file and saved it using .sh extension and executed using sh test.sh command.
This tool does some BIOS related configurations

Comment: Add `#!/bin/bash` to the top. Then either `chmod 0755 filename.sh` to set the execute bit (and then run it with `./filename.sh`) or just run it with `bash filename.sh`. When you use `sh` you are calling a POSIX compliant shell that lacks much of the functionality of bash (sh is dash (Debian Almquist Shell) A shell script just executes the same series of commands you could execute on the command line as long as you don't change the environment the script runs in. So put exactly what you run on the command line in the script, (noting `arg1` and `arg2` are `"$1"` and `"$2"` inside the script.

Comment: Please show script

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you executed the file originally by way of a relative path, `./executable.sh`. You must use the full path in your shell script or `cd` to the correct directory from within the script.

`/path/to/executable.sh arg1 arg 2`

or

`cd /path/to
./executable.sh arg1 arg2`

I suggest the first option, however you do have some other options:

1. Add the location of `executable.sh` to your `$PATH`.
2. Place `executable.sh` somewhere accessible from everywhere, namely `/usr/local/bin`.

Do not forget to set permissions for this file, which can be done with `chmod +x executable.sh` or `chmod 0755 executable.sh`.

Note that this will work for any executable files, not just `.sh`.

Comment: Executable is not of shell format it's an **ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, for GNU/LINUX 2.4.0, stripped**. I tried to add executable command in shell script file which is failing with error No Such File or Directory

Comment: This should work for any type of executable file, be it .sh or .exe or otherwise. Can you edit your question and add the script?